# Sample and hold: fast switching

Tags: operational-amplifier, sample-and-hold

[image: circuit]

Consider the circuit above. I'm struggling to answer the following question:

> Suppose the source of “Analog In” to your sample and hold has a
>   Thevenin output  resistance of 10K and you want to keep the sample
>   time (when “In 1,3” is high) to a  maximum of 1uSec . Is this a
>   problem? Why or why not? If it is a problem, how do you  fix it? (Make
>   sure you do not increase voltage droop with your fix.)

I've been staring at the question and don't even know where to start. The only thing I can think of is an op amp buffer, since they seem to fix every problem related to impedance.

Note that this *is* homework, I'm looking for hints that could point me in the right direction and/or a deeper understanding of this circuit.

Comment: hint: Analog In has some resistance, and there's a capacitor, so you get an RC low-pass filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the circuit as voltage source charging the capacitor through the output resistance. Will you be able to charge the capacitor in 1us?

Comment: Your answer and @helloworld922's comment made it much clearer. It's awfully simple, thanks.